# Hide QWidget but keep the empty space, so there is not effect in the layout

Tags: qt, qlayout, qvboxlayout

There is a `QVBoxLayout` in which many `QHBoxLayout` were added. Each `QHBoxLayout` has the same set of widgets, in principle. In fact I'm hiding some of the widgets and this causes the other widgets to get bigger in order to occupy the space.

Is it possible to keep the empty space? Ideally, I would like to have the other widgets in the same position with the same size.

Comment: I think I once did this, using a QStackedLayout to hold the 'disappearing' content.  But I no longer have the code to hand.

Answer (score 1):

`QGridLayout` allows to set a fixed relative stretch for all its columns and rows.

In the following example, no resizing occurs when widgets are hidden:

```
QGridLayout * grid = new QGridLayout();

setLayout(grid);

// adding widgets one under another
grid->addWidget(new QLabel("Hallo"),   0, 0);
grid->addWidget(new QLabel("Spencer"), 1, 0);

QWidget * f = new QLabel("Bar");
grid->addWidget(f,                     2, 0);

QWidget * b = new QLabel("Bar");
grid->addWidget(w,                     3, 0);

// define the relative proportions of the rows
grid->setRowStretch(0, 1);
grid->setRowStretch(1, 1);
grid->setRowStretch(2, 1);
grid->setRowStretch(3, 1);

// it's even possible to set a stretch if no content is present in that row
grid->setRowStretch(4, 2);

b->hide();
f->hide();
```

So, you can hide any Widget you like and the overall proportions won't change. Important are the `setRow/ColumnStretch`calls which define the relative proportions of the grid cells.

Comment: This is nice, but it works not quite correctly if we use non-zero layoutVerticalSpace property. In this case, hiding, for example, the last row will result in vertical shift of all remaining rows.